# Libgdx box2d how to get the current body position

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

Why doesn't this work?

```
for (Body body : worldBodies) {
    if (body.getPosition().y<0)
    {
        sprite.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that body origin is at its center so what you should check is actually

```
    if (body.getPosition().y - bodyShapeHeight/2f < 0 ) //bodyShapeHeight is just a variable you have to create
    {
        ...
```

Unfortunately there is no like bodyHeight - it depends on Fixture. If you have only one and its aligned to center you probably can use

```
    body.getFixtureList().first().getShape().getRadius();
```

instead of using additional variable but if not you have to remember shape height in some **bodyShapeHeight** variable